# What does a hash (#) followed by a number mean in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

For example, the #1 in:

```
f:is-subordinate($M, $E, f:direct-reports#1)
```

from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#d7e22590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you point to is a higher-order function that takes another function as a parameter.  The `f:direct-reports#1` denotes the function named `f:direct-reports` that takes 1 argument - the number after the hash is referred to as the function's *arity* - and this `function#arity` syntax is the way you refer to the function itself as a first-class object, as opposed to calling the function and making use of its return value.

Comment: Thanks - useful to know the difference between calling the function itself as an object and using its return value.

Answer (score 4):

This is called the arity, and it's the number of parameters required by a function.
If you don't have any hash (#), the arity of the function is 0.

Here, it refers to a `direct-reports` function which take a single parameter.

With arity, you can have several functions with the same name, but a number of parameters which differs.